# MySQL Efficiency - multiple text columns, or multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working with a web app that currently stores millions of notes, and certain notes are sent from 1 user type to another, and if a message should go to multiple user types it requires multiple rows (partially because certain user types will get messages with names, other user types will get the message, but names are hidden, for compliance/security).

current table structure - PK, note (text), userid (sending message - int indexed), source (tinyint indexed), destination (tinyint indexed), timestamp, read (tinyint indexed)

Examples:

"Client" user sends message to "staff" user - "Joe Smith said XYZ. What do I do?" - 1 note/row, source = client, destination = staff

The above presents no issue. However, here's where multiple rows are coming in:

- "staff user" message to staff, client and vendor
  Staff to Staff version: "Joe Smith is delaying the process, we need to do something". - 1 note/row, source = staff, destination = staff

Staff to Client Version: "Joe Smith is delaying the process, we need to do something" - 1 note/row, source = staff, destination = client

Staff to Vendor Version: "The client is delaying the process, we are working on doing something about this issue." - 1 note/row, source = staff, destination = vendor

In these scenarios (very common for message to go to 2 or 3 parties), either the staff user is entering both versions on the screen at once, submitting and they are going in as separate rows to proper parties, OR, Staff receives message from 1 party, modifies it, and sends to another party.

My question is, would it be better to have a table structured as follows:
PK, original_note (text), userID, timestamp, staff_version (text), vendor_version (text), client_version (text)
Where each message is just 1 row and the respective version the user type sees is pulled by column based on who they are.

I'm asking in terms of speed and practicality. We are to the point of 9 million notes, and for compliance purposes, we can't really get rid of any for a while.

I've tried searching on this topic but I'm not sure I am coming up with good keywords, since I haven't been able to find anything addressing this type of question/scenario.

Comment: Are your tables indexed properly (show us your indexes)? What do your queries look like (show us your queries)? Have you timed any of your queries (how long does it take to make a standard call)?

Comment: I'm sure that my indexes and queries are as optimal as they can be, and we don't have a speed problem yet. I'm trying to plan ahead an theorize on what to do a year or 2 from now

Comment: I guess I'm basically asking if there's someone knowledgeable that might know speed differences between having 3 or 4 large text columns in a table and selecting 1 or 2 of them, vs querying 3 times the number of rows looking for the proper rows you want to pull, based off of 2 or 3 tinyint 1 unsigned indexed cols

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to solve a superficial problem with a database solution. When you go to `echo` the note then can you simply check if the user has permissions to view the names and just show/hide based on that?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, unfortunately no, the entire message sometimes must be re-worded, it is not names along. Depends on the content of the message, which is why we have people that have to read the messages, reword and distribute to proper parties. So the multiple columns or rows are definitely necessary

Comment: "I'm sure that my indexes and queries are as optimal as they can be" I'm not going to judge your skill set but providing actual code is more helpful to us then theoretical what ifs.  Side note your second scenario does not scale well if say you need to add another type of note version say for an administrator.

Comment: I understand, but we there's probably 25 different ways we query notes depending where you are in the system and what you're trying to look at, just doesn't seem practical. I can just tell you that all the where clauses are looking at only combos of tinyint 1 indexes if at all possible. There's a couple of situations querying LIKEs on the notes, but they are infrequently used and people understand those operations are slower. And for those few, I have plans to change things slightly to handle without the LIKE, down the line. Your point about scalability is noted, and a great point

Comment: @livewire1407 From a normalization standpoint (and that is usually a good idea) and from your description, you need three tables, one with base data (id, date, from, ...), one with the messagetext, one with the receipients (at least if your text is regarded as "same for all, except we do it manually", that depends on your definition of what a message is, and you might merged it into the 2nd table). Any derivation from that for optimization purposes would require knowledge about your actual queries, although I don't think 9 million rows need much more optimization than correct indexes.